# Copy contents of one table to another table in a different Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a SQL table similar to (call it `UserTable`)

```
+--------+-----------+----------+
| UserId | FirstName | LastName |
+--------+-----------+----------+
|    123 | Bob       | Smith    |
|    456 | John      | Doe      |
+--------+-----------+----------+
```

On a different server I have a table (call it `UserBackupTable`)

```
+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
| Location | UserId | FirstName | LastName |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
| A        |    123 | Bob       | Smith    |
| B        |    456 | John      | Doe      |
+----------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

The two tables are identical except for the addition of one column (`Location`). I would like to backup/copy `UserTable` to `UserBackupTable` in a better way than

```
var dataToCopy = userDb.UserTable.Select(user => new UserBackup
{
    Location = _location,
    FirstName = user.FirstName,
    LastName = user.LastName
}).ToList();
backupDb.UserBackups.AddRange(dataToCopy);
```

This works but isn't very efficient for me when I have 40+ columns to have to manually type out. These are database first models in case that is needed.

Comment: In the time you typed this question you could've written those 40 assignments. What kind of solution are you actually looking for? Is raw SQL an option?

Comment: I did actually write it and it works, just feels...wrong. Like there should be a better way.

Comment: There is SqlBulkCopy class , it lets you copy large amounts of data using DataReader from one DB to another, fast, with transaction support, progress reports and ability to cancel the process. I even successfully used it to copy data from Oracle to MSSQL db in the past. But you would have to write a little more than five lines of code to do it https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score -1):

Can you not just do this at the database layer, rather than via an ORM, e.g.

```
SELECT *
INTO [backupDb].[dbo].[UserBackups]
FROM [dbo].[UserTable]
```

You'll need to modify the above depending how you do it, e.g. incrementally, or recreating the whole backup table each time depending on the size of your data (just make sure you drop the existing table and select into its replacement as part of a transaction) but you could just automate it via SQL Server Agent or something.

Note that SELECT INTO creates a new target table, so that wouldn't be suitable for an incremental backup approach.

Comment: I could, but the whole point was to keep it in program using Entity.

Comment: Why's that the point? Surely the whole point is to find the best solution? :-) You can execute arbitrary SQL using EF if you like. It sounds like more of a database maintenance task to me.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted but a comment to explain why would be helpful. It absolutely answers the question, as I've used this solution many times over many years. If it's because it's a non-EF solution then I don't believe this was clearly stated in the question.